# Passing context object to async operation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have an MVC4 application, and I have several instances where it would be beneficial to "fire and forget" on a few method calls.  These methods are longer running and shouldn't block the response back to the user.  I realize async controller methods don't help me here, but in a particular controller method I would like to call a method using await keywords against an async function.

Easy enough, but for each request the application builds up a [ThreadStatic] context that becomes available to any method call along the chain.  This context contains things like the current user, etc.

So the async methods also need this context.  Is there a preferred pattern for passing this context into the async method other than simply passing it into the method itself?  That can be done, but doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: You do realize it's not just async controller methods that "don't help [you] here", right? Async/await, in general, blocks the calling method from returning until the async task has completed. It doesn't matter whether it's a controller action or some method in some class that's async, you're still not getting "fire and forget" functionality from it.

Comment: True.  Good point, and thanks for the clarification.  I have used System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew() in the past for this.  I was thinking async/await would be a shortcut for this, but as you pointed out, it is not.

Comment: I think the confusion probably comes from async in scripting languages like JavaScript, where it is kind of fire and forget, requiring a callback if you want to so some other work after. In ASP.NET, it's about web server threads. Async returns the thread to the pool to field other requests when it's in a wait state, but the calling method still must complete the task before it returns. StartNew() is not a great idea though, especially in a web server environment. Look into an actual backgrounding or task scheduling solution.

Comment: Cool.  Can you elaborate on why StartNew() isn't a great idea in a web environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *best* approach is to pass it into the method, or use a dependency injection library.

However, if you really do want to pass an "ambient" context without actually passing it as an argument, then you can use the logical call context (`CallContext.LogicalGetData` / `CallContext.LogicalSetData`) to store immutable data. I have a more detailed writeup [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).